# Java - public int indexOf(int ch)

Tags: java, string, char, int, indexof

I came across following:

```
public int indexOf(int ch)
```

as per http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int) when I was revising some String related Java concepts.

As per my knowledge, when we use method `indexOf()` for `java.lang.String`, the parameter is supposed to be `char` and hence I was assuming it to be

```
public int indexOf(char ch)
```

So, please explain me why is it `public int indexOf(int ch)`.

Comment: Is it because it treats that character as Unicode Code Point, which (Unicode Code Point) in turn is an int or has data type int?

Comment: My guess is that, since its dealing with Unicode code points, it just needs a wider range than the one provided by `char`. `char` is just 8 bits, while `int` is 32 bits.

Comment: @Guildenstern `char` is 16 bits.  Which was enough for the original Unicode, but not any more.

Comment: Scroll up to the top of the `String` javadoc and you'll see: "A String represents a string in the UTF-16 format in which supplementary characters are represented by surrogate pairs (see the section Unicode Character Representations in the Character class for more information). Index values refer to char code units, so a supplementary character uses two positions in a String."

Comment: @Vikram see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/26080888/1966247 hope it will clear your concept about chars and ints :)

Answer (score 3):

Unicode contains many more than 2^16 characters. Java 'char' and 'String' use a Unicode Transformation Format (UTF-16) to represent the full set of characters. Characters in the Base Multilingual Plane are represented as a single 16-bit 'char'. The rest are represented by a *surrogate pair*: two special 16-bit values from a set reserved for this purpose.

An alternative representation is UTF-32. In this representation, each character is a single 32-bit item, period.

For example, Cuneiform is out there in the SMP; the first character of the block is U+12000. In UTF-32, that's just 0x12000. In UTF-16, it's `"\uD808\uDC00"`. [Here's some pictures.](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/12000/index.htm)

The `Character` and `String` classes (amongst others), provide a few methods that operate on UTF-32 characters for convenience. You're asking about one of them. Whenever you see 'int' as the datatype of a character, that's what the 'int' contains: a UTF-32 value. It's not hard to see how it can be more convenient to do some operations with a single UTF-32 value instead of a pair of surrogates.

Note that this has nothing to do with composed and non-composed accents. á can be represented in Unicode as either one or two UTF-16 characters, but there are no surrogates involved. All three of U+0061 (a), U+00E1 (a with precomposed accent), and U+0301 (composing acute accent) are ordinary BMP characters. So, even in UTF-32, you can have a two-item sequence: U+0061, U+0301.

The ICU4J library provides a more complete set of UTF-32 classes and methods.

Answer (score 1):

**Every char have an int value that you can use to get that char as well you can convert a chart into int the same way by assigning a char to an int variable
try the following lines**

```
char ch = 65;
System.out.println(ch);
int i = 'A';
System.out.println(i);
```

I'm using char values in a loop and it is allowed just because every char have an int value.
try this code it will print out alphabets from A to Z and its equivalent int values

```
    for(char j = 'A'; j <= 'Z'; j++){
        System.out.println("int "+((int) j)+" = "+j);
    }
```